# SyntaxError: python Arabic encoding

Tags: python, encoding, arabic

I have this Code -I am using Python 2.7- :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- Coding: UTF-8 -*-
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import StanfordTokenizer
sentence = u"السلام عليكم و رحمة الله و بركاته"
print StanfordTokenizer().tokenize(sentence)
```

I saved the code in a file called example.py, when I write python example.py in the terminal I get the following error:

```
File "example.py", line 5 
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file example.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I already declared the type of encoding as UTF-8. So what is the problem? However, if I run the code line by line in the terminal it is working and no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the first or second line must match the regular
>       expression "^[ \t\v]*#.*?coding[:=][ \t]*([-_.a-zA-Z0-9]+)".

[source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Your encoding declaration does not match that regex. The `c` needs to be lowercase.